# returning value from command bus

Tags: java, c#, php, domain-driven-design

I've read upon command bus a lot used in on a couple of projects its awesome. I keep reading though that the command is not supposed to return anything to the controller; however, there are certain times that I feel like I must absolutely return a value for example:

```
$product = $this->dispatch(AddProductCommand::class);

return redirect()->route('route', $attributes = ['product_slug' => $product->slug]);
```

I need to grab the slug of the newly created product because for the redirect the route needs the slug . Is this bad practice and if so what would be a cleaner way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to implement it in a completely asynchronous style as you use web framework which is synchronous by design.

If you use framework that allows for async requests or (even better) you have separated UI concerns (like redirect) from the backend you can subscribe for ProductAdded event with a callback that fires redirect.